# Any suggestion on the paper  " Hodge cycles on abelian varieties"  ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have to understand Deligne's paper" Hodge cycles on abelian variesties",but I find it very difficlut to read ,even though I have already spent several months to learn the etale cohomology.Is there any sugestion for understanding this paper,or any auxiliary reading material?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: There is a paper of Gross on the Chowla--Selberg formula (from the early 80s, I think) which may have served as partial inspiration for Deligne.  It is more accessible, I would guess.

Also, have you looked in the Motives volumes?  I don't remember if there is anything expository about absolute Hodge cycles there, but you could look.

Comment: -1, because I just don't like questions like this.  I guess a "correct answer" would be like Emerton's comment: a more accessible prequel.  But what OP is really asking is for someone to explain that paper here.  Asking about individual remarks in the paper seems like a good idea, because it advances the community.  But "this paper is hard" isn't much of a question, and is better suited as an impetus to set up a student seminar on the topic than to start a discussion here.  In any case, the actual answer is: "read papers you like, and come back to this one later."

Comment: I like Schappacher's book Periods of Hecke Characters. It's also available for cheap.

Comment: Have you read Deligne's series, Theorie de Hodge?

Comment: Seconding Theo's comment. A more focused question would be helpful - part of being or becoming a good student is to work out more precisely why/where one is stuck. (I speak as someone who is rather slow at doing this, but it *does* need to be done.)